# How to use model methods in django templates with class based view

Tags: python, django

I've defined methods in my model, and I'm trying to use it in django template, which is rendered using `ListView`

My model looks like this:

```
class Book(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
  price = models.IntegerField()
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)

  def get_total_sum(self):
        return super().objects.all().filter(user=self.user).aggregate(models.Sum('price'))
```

My view:

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

from book.models import Book

class BookView(ListView):
  template_name = 'book.html'

  # I'm using this to order book by created date
  def get_queryset(self):
    return Book.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).order_by('-created_at')
```

And my template:

```
Total books: {{ object_list|length }}
Total price of all books: # I've no idea how to display them here, when using class based view
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to use custom `templatetags`:

Follow these steps:

1. Create a folder `templatetags` inside your app directory
2. Create a file inside e.g `book_filter.py` and `__init__.py`
3. Inside `book_filter.py`  copy below filter.

## book_filter.py

```
from django import template
egister = template.Library()

@register.filter
def total_price(amounts):
    total = 0
    for amount in amounts:
        total += amount.price
    return total
```

Now in your html file, do the following:

```
{% load book_filter %}

Total price of all books: {{object_list|total_price}}
```

Use this link for reference: [custom-template-tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use `Book.get_total_sum` in a template, you need to make it a property.

```
  @property
  def get_total_sum(self):
      return super().objects.all().filter(user=self.user).aggregate(models.Sum('price'))
```

in the template

```
{{ book.get_total_sum }}
```

Another way is to inject the value you want by obtaining it with Python code in the view `get_context` method and injecting it into the context. For a computed value that is different for each Book instance, this obviously does not work, and a property is ideal. Custom template tags are ideal when the code is not naturally bound to one class as a property